# How to align two textfields

Tags: html, css, jsp, struts2

I need to align two textfields in the same row, but one on the left and the other in the page center. I'm trying this:

```xhtml
    <div class="pure-g margin-1-0">
            <div class="pure-u-1-4">
                <label for="tipologia"> 
                    <fmt:message key="label.table.lavorazioni.spese.tipologia"/> 
                    
                </label> 
                
                <s:textfield cssClass="pure-u-23-24 required"  size="35"  name="" id="tipologia" /> 
            </div>
            <div class="pure-u-1-4" style="align:center">
                <label for="valore"> 
                    <fmt:message key="label.table.lavorazioni.spese.valore"/> 
                    
                </label>
                
                <s:textfield cssClass="pure-u-23-24 required" size="35"  name="" id="valore" /> 
            </div> 
        </div>
```

But I see the left one correctly but the other remains next to the first and not at the center.

Any suggestion?

Comment: simple. Use `theme="simple"` in the Struts2 tags, but be aware that then you need to add field errors by yourself using appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

To align elements inside the container use `text-align` css rule. Struts2 tags use themes to generate additional content in the forms. So it could break the initial design.

```html
   <div class="pure-g margin-1-0">
            <div class="pure-u-1-4"  style="text-align:center">
                <label for="tipologia"> 
                    <fmt:message key="label.table.lavorazioni.spese.tipologia"/> 

                </label> 

                <input type="text" class="pure-u-23-24 required"  size="35"  name="" id="tipologia" /> 
            </div>
            <div class="pure-u-1-4" style="text-align:center">
                <label for="valore"> 
                    <fmt:message key="label.table.lavorazioni.spese.valore"/> 

                </label>

                <input type="text" class="pure-u-23-24 required" size="35"  name="" id="valore" /> 
            </div> 
        </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/338e5qx1/)

Comment: I've tried this solution, but it centers only the text on the textbox and not the entire textbox

Comment: run code snippet or jsfiddle and you will see that both fields are centered.

Comment: I need to align two textfield in the same row, but one on the left and the other in the page center. Your code put the textfield at the center of the pafe, but into 2 differents rows